# Can not Start Rancher Agent in Docker

Tags: docker, rancher

I am trying Rancher (v.1.2.3) and I am not able to run the agent in the nodes.

1) I've installed the racher server in one node with the following command:

```
sudo docker run -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 80:8080 rancher/server:v1.2.3
```

2) Then I go to Add Host, and Ranchers gives me the command to add it.

3) I go to the Node 1, and put the following:

```
sudo docker run -d --privileged -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run /docker.sock -v /var/lib/rancher:/var/lib/rancher rancher/agent:v1.1.2 http:/xxx/v1/scripts/D822D98E34752ABCDE:1890908200000:RASZERSE
```

4) The command line returns

```
docker: Error response from daemon: containerd: container did not start before the specified
```

I don't know what is going wrong, I think the container can not access to Rancher Server, but If do a

```
curl http:/xxx/v1/scripts/D822D98E34752ABCDE:1890908200000:RASZERSE
```

I can access it. In addition this is my IPTABLES:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N CATTLE_FORWARD
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --clamp-  mss-to-pmtu
-A FORWARD -j CATTLE_FORWARD
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker_gwbridge -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -o docker_gwbridge -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker_gwbridge ! -o docker_gwbridge -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker_gwbridge -o docker_gwbridge -j DROP
-A CATTLE_FORWARD -m mark --mark 0x668a0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i docker_gwbridge -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i docker0 -o docker_gwbridge -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
```

Ubuntu v14.04
Docker v1.12.3

It would be greatly appreciated if you could help me.

Thanks

Comment: May not help, but why don't you run the latest tag of the rancher server? It runs a more modern version of the agent. Worth a try.

Comment: also your error string is incomplete `docker: Error response from daemon: containerd: container did not start before the specified`  <-- maybe has more info explaining the issue

Answer (score 0):

The full error is presumably "containerd: container did not start before the specified timeout", which means Docker isn't starting the container.  Rebooting the host will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

If the nodes which you are using, ie the one where you start rancher/server:v1.2.3 and the one where you start the agent are the same, then there could be internal port access issue.

Rancher uses UDP services/ports like 500 for internal communications. These must be permitted, maybe by adding to firewalld zones etc. Issues might occur if you use managed networking.